Excel Sumproduct with multiple criteria lookup in two tables
For a report, I need to calculate the SUMPRODUCT()  of amounts in a data table multiplied by a factor value determined using a lookup table, the factor value (and thus column) to use depends on several conditions.I've made many attempts (and research) with SUMPRODUCT() and INDEX/MATCH() condition (tried also INDIRECT/ROWS uses) but I just can't get it to work properly.I'd appreciate some help to figure out what I'm doing wrong or any workable alternative (helper columns rows not being an alternative as my actual report and the lookup table are larger than the sample used to illustrate my question.Many thanks for looking at this question.
For the report in cells A1:G5 (sample), I need to calculate the SUMPRODUCT()  of amount in data table (A28:M38) multiplied by a factor (F29:M38) value determined using the lookup table (A12:E24), only a sample) and based on the following conditions;




A
B
C
D
E
F
G




1
Template
Report A

D
E
F
G


2
B


?





3
E








4
F










Scope is equal to value in cell B1 (Report A)

For Asset "B" (row 2) , make the sumproduct for assets "B" and "GB", for row 3, Asset "E", for row 4 asset "F"

the factor value to use in the Data table is determined by looking up the Factor column in the lookup table (LookupTable) as per the following criteria ;

the factor depends on the column : match between column in row 1 and column "column" in the lookup table. E.g. for the formula in cell D2, the column is  "D", thus the factor are those in rows 13 to 18 in the lookup table

the factor depends on the asset and entity type with the specfic additional criteria;

if asset is GB or F, use the corresponding factor (given the column letter matches)

if entity_type is populated with B or I and the asset is B or E, then use the corresponding factor (for entity_type B or I)

else use the factor corresponding to the asset (B or E)






Thus for D2 the result expected would = 1000*.21+2000*.2+1200*.2+3000*.33
for D3, the result should be =1000*0 + 1100*.02+1000*0.1
or D4, the result should be =1000*.8 + 500*0
The lookup table



asset
entity_type
active
column
lookup_column




GB

N
D
Factor1



B
Y
D
Factor2



I
Y
D
Factor3


B

Y
D
Factor1


E

Y
D
Factor1


F


D
Factor8


GB

Y
E
Factor4



B
Y
E
Factor5



I
Y
E
Factor6


B

Y
E
Factor7


E

Y
E
Factor7


F

Y
E
Factor8



The data table;



Scope
Name
Amount
entity_type
asset
Factor1
Factor2
Factor3
Factor4
Factor5
Factor6
Factor7
Factor8




Report A
CPY 1
1000
I
E
.2
.25








Report B
CPY 2
1500

B

.1








Report A
CPY 1
1000

B
.21
.15








Report A
CPY 3
2000

B
.2
.25








Report A
CPY 4
1200
B
GB
.2
.25
.3
.4
.5
.6
.7
.8


Report A
CPY 5
1100

E
.02
.4








Report A
CPY 1
1000

F
.22
.05
.3
.4
.5
.6
.7
.8


Report A
CPY 6
500
I
F
.12
.45








Report A
CPY7
3000

GB
.33
.2
.3
.4
.5
.6
.7
.8


Report A
CPY 8
1000
B
E
.25
.1
.3
.4
.5
.6
.7
.8



The formula for D2;
=SUMPRODUCT(
    --(Data[Scope] = $B$1);
    --(IF(
        $A2 = "B";
        (Data[asset] = "B") + (Data[asset] = "GB");
        Data[asset] = $A2
    ));
    INDEX(
        Data;
        0;
        MATCH(
            INDEX(
                LookupTable[lookup_column];
                MATCH(
                    1;
                    (LookupTable[asset] = IF($A2 = "B"; "B";$A2)) *
                    (LookupTable[entity_type] = IF(OR(Data[entity_type] = "B";Data[entity_type] = "I");Data[entity_type];"")) *
                    (LookupTable[column] = D1);
                    0
                )
            );
            Data[#Headers];
            0
        )
    ) ; Data[Amount]
) 

For what I can see from the "evaluate formula" the problem lies in the 2nd index(match()) as I can see it it has an array of 12 items with last 2 being #N/A (there are 10 rows in the data table) thus array size are not equal but they should not be, should they ?
If adding IFNA(;0) in the 2nd index/match(), the end result is 0 and it would pick up only Factor1 (which is not what I want).
That's basically where I'm stuck.
Second formula (picks always a single factor value => the 1st one from INDEX())
=SUMPRODUCT(
    --(Data[Scope] = $B$1);
    --(IF(
        OR($A2 = "B"; $A2 = "E");
        (Data[asset] = $A2) + (Data[asset] = IF($A2 = "B"; "GB"; ""));
        Data[asset] = $A2
    ));
    Data[Amount]*
    IFERROR(
        --(
            INDEX(
                Data;
                0;
                MATCH(
                    IF(
                        OR($A2="B"; $A2="E");
                        IF(
                            OR(Data[entity_type] ="B"; Data[entity_type] ="I");
                            INDEX(
                                LookupTable[lookup_column];
                                MATCH(
                                    1;
                                    (LookupTable[entity_type] = Data[entity_type]) *
                                    (LookupTable[column] = D$1);
                                    0
                                )
                            );
                            INDEX(
                                LookupTable[lookup_column];
                                MATCH(
                                    1;
                                    (LookupTable[asset] = $A2) *
                                    (LookupTable[column] = D$1);
                                    0
                                )
                            )
                        );
                        INDEX(
                            LookupTable[lookup_column];
                            MATCH(
                                1;
                                (LookupTable[asset] = $A2) *
                                (LookupTable[column] = D$1);
                                0
                            )
                        )
                    );
                    Data[#Headers];
                    0
                )
            )
        );
        0
    )
)

Excel screenshot

'For Asset "B" (row 2) , make the sumproduct for assets "B" and "GB", for row 3, Asset "E", for row 4 asset "F"'  do you mean: For Asset "B" (row 3) , make the sumproduct for assets "B" and "GB", for row 2, Asset "E", for row 4 asset "F" ?

"or D4, the result should be =1000*.8 + 500*0" -- I don't see 0.8 anywhere... can you make sure the sample data and your examples match? Also maybe highlighting the relevant numbers for a given example in the tables may make what is supposed to happen clearer?

Just added row number in the 1st table to clarify which rows are referred to in the example (and corrected the asset values).
The .0.8 is Factor8 (far right of Data table). The Excel screenshot added should also facilitate proper reading and overview of the topic. Hope this is clearer @cybernetic.nomad

In the Lookup table Report A, asset B for column D has lookup column Factor1 which, in the Data table is .21 not .15, so I am confused about the expected results for cell D2.

@Clif, I fixed the example so that it matches the excel screenshot and sample data provided. The difficulty I find in the working it out this topic is the part where the formula should lookup the factor based on entity_type if the asset if B or E (and returning not a single value but an array of factor values) . The part based on the asset type is ok.

With the  modified formula, a factor value is well picked-up for each row in the data table, but it's alway the same factor  (in this case factor1) and not the one depending on either the entity_type or the asset. I guess this is because the index()  function does only pass the 1st value and not the array retrieved ( applies to the match() as I well I suppose (see edited formula)

unfortunately I don't have time to rewrite your formula now, however instead of INDEX & MATCH you could use FILTER, making your formula more simple and easier to fix eventual issues.

This formula using Excel365 functions allowed me to achieve the desired result;
=SUM(
BYROW(
    Data;
    LAMBDA(row;
        LET(
       et; INDEX(row; MATCH("entity_type"; Data[#Headers]; 0));
       as; INDEX(row; MATCH("asset"; Data[#Headers]; 0));
       amt; INDEX(row; MATCH("Amount"; Data[#Headers]; 0));
       scope; INDEX(row; MATCH("Scope"; Data[#Headers]; 0));
       template; $A$3;
       asset_filter; OR(
           (template = "B") * ((as = "B") + (as = "GB"));
           (template = "E") * (as = "E");(template = "F") * (as = "F")
            );
            factor_col; IF(
             OR(as = "B"; as = "E");
              IF(
                 OR(et = "B"; et = "I");
                 INDEX(
                  LookupTable[lookup_column];
                  MATCH(1; (LookupTable[entity_type] = et) * (LookupTable[column] = D$1); 0)
                    );
                    INDEX(
                        LookupTable[lookup_column];
                        MATCH(1; (LookupTable[asset] = as) * (LookupTable[column] = D$1); 0)
                    )
                );
                INDEX(
                    LookupTable[lookup_column];
                    MATCH(1; (LookupTable[asset] = as) * (LookupTable[column] = D$1); 0)
                )
            );
            factor_value; INDEX(row; MATCH(factor_col; Data[#Headers]; 0));
            IF(scope = $B$1; IF(asset_filter; amt * factor_value; 0); 0)
        )
    )
)
)

The BYROW(Data, LAMBDA(...)) processes each row of the Data table individually and the LAMBDA function (which I discovered) allows to define a series of operations for each row.
The LET Function enables to define and reuse variables, which makes the final calculation easier to formulate.
The factor_col variable identifies which factor column (e.g., Factor1, Factor2) to use based on the entity_type and asset.
The trick is that I want to use the entity_type (B or I ) when populated for asset B or E (and not for F or GB) => this was the difficult part to handle with the formula, together with the fact that index() in the sumproduct was not passing all values from the array but only one. For that reason I looked a way to process data on a row by row basis.
Hope others find this useful


The following formula is used to populate the Value1 and Value2 columns: =IFERROR(INDEX(Data[[Factor1]:[Factor8]],AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Data[Scope])-ROW(Data[[#Headers],[Scope]]))/(Data[[Scope]:[Scope]]=$B$2)/(Data[[asset]:[asset]]=LookupTable[@[asset]:[asset]]),COLUMNS($F13:F13)),AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN(Data[[#Headers],[Factor1]:[Factor8]])-COLUMN(Data[[asset]:[asset]]))/(Data[[#Headers],[Factor1]:[Factor8]]=LookupTable[@[lookup_column]:[lookup_column]]),1))*INDEX(Data[[Amount]:[Amount]],AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Data[Scope])-ROW(Data[[#Headers],[Scope]]))/(Data[[Scope]:[Scope]]=$B$2)/(Data[[asset]:[asset]]=LookupTable[@[asset]:[asset]]),COLUMNS($F13:F13))),0)
The following is used to populate cells beneath D and E: =SUM(SUMPRODUCT((LookupTable[[Value1]:[Value2]])*(LookupTable[[asset]:[asset]]=$A3)*(LookupTable[[column]:[column]]=D$2)),IF($A3="B",SUMPRODUCT((LookupTable[[Value1]:[Value2]])*(LookupTable[[asset]:[asset]]="GB")*(LookupTable[[column]:[column]]=D$2)),0))
Note that I don't understand how D3 has three factors when there are only two instances of asset E.

thanks for this proposition.
There are 3 instances of E (check last row ;-) of data table) .
Your solution works for the various types of asset, only missing the use of the entity type.
Thus for D3 and asset= E the sum would be 10000 (no Factor3 value) + 1100.02 (Factor1 for asset E) +1000*0.1 (Factor because entity_type=B and prevails of asset) .
I thought of using helper columns (can't use VBA at the office) but my actual template has (for now) 6 columns & 72 rows in the lookup table. Potentially, data will have up to 48 factors (& thousand rows), I was trying to avoid that.

Sorry, I did miss the third value of E. I think that computationally it would be better to use helper columns and lookup a value once than to have the formulas under D and E have to look them up repeatedly. If you are open to the use of helper columns, I can keep working on this.

thanks a lot for the idea. Helper columns would add complexity to the file which I'm trying to avoid given the audience it is meant to. In the mean time I managed to work out a solution using Excel365 functions (BYROW, MAP , ....)  which I'll post here

Glad that you found a solution and will look forward to seeing it.
